# Can't get ledpar to work with section headings

Tags: sectioning, errors, ledmac

I'm trying to create a bilingual critical edition with Latin on the left page and English on the right. I'm trying to figure out `ledpar` and I can't get the following example to compile. It compiles just fine if I comment out the two section headings, but with the section headings LaTeX throws the error on line 19 (which calls the `\Pages` macro) that says

```
You can't use \lastbox in vertical mode.
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ledmac, ledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\section{blah}  
lorem ipsum\pend
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\section{blerg}
asdf.
\pend
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This compiles for me and produces output with a few `overfull` warnings.  Do you perhaps have some auxiliary files left over from a previous run?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I actually don't use ledpar very often; I thought it was much more similar to `ledmac`.  There are a few things wrong with the code you have above, but they are not the problem.  This should work:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ledmac, ledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\leavevmode\section{blah}% <--
lorem ipsum
\pend
\endnumbering% <--
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\leavevmode\section{blerg}
asdf.
\pend
\endnumbering% <--
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

My earlier comment was wrong: the `\section` commands do need to be inside the `\pstart ... \pend` (unlike in `ledmac`), but the `\leavevmode` will get rid of your error messages if you are using older versions of these packages; e.g.:

```
ledmac.sty    2005/03/24 v0.7 LaTeX port of EDMAC
ledpar.sty    2005/04/08 v0.3b ledmac extension for parallel texts
```

Note that newer versions are available on CTAN: [ledmac](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/ledmac.html); [ledpar](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/ledpar.html).  It is possible they have fixed this issue.

**Edit:**

Now that I have both old and new (June 2012) versions of the packages, I can confirm that the `\leavevmode` is no longer necessary.  (Though nothing changes if you leave it in.)

Answer (score 2):

The new version of eledmac (1.1) provides commands for sectioning inside numbered text (and with critical notes)

Comment: I'm not clear on the link between `eledmac` and `ledpar`: could you explain this?

Comment: Ledmac is the basis, which allows line numbering and critical comments;

Comment: and ledpar is an extension which allows parallel typesetting

Answer (score 0):

The new version of eledmac/eledpar (1.12 / 1.8) which will be released soon provide better tool to manage your case. It provides eledsection.

That is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ledmac, ledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsection{blah}  
\pend
\pstart
lorem ipsum\pend
\end{Leftside}
\begin{Rightside}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsection{blerg}
\pend
\pstart
asdf.
\pend
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

I invite you to wait some time the new version be posted on CTAN